# ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the RELOAD privilege(s) for this operation

Tags: php, mysql, database, cpanel

When I run command `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` in cpanel, I get:

> ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the RELOAD privilege(s) for this operation

How can I fix that issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As per [ask], please do not upload images or code or errors. Show them as text instead. Anyway it's unclear, because the script you've shown simply makes a http request to an endpoint. We've no idea what happens at the other end, whether it creates a database user successfully or not. Anyway, contact the hosting company support if you think it's not connecting to an account that you think you've created properly. There's not much we can do about it.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
grant reload on *.* to 'test'@'localhost';
```